# SQL syntax error saying command not properly ended

Tags: sql

These are my tables:

- section (course id, sec id, semester, year, building, room number, time slot id)
- takes (ID, course id, sec id, semester, year, grade)

I want to get rows from take that meet the conditions and the get rows from the section relation meeting takes conditions

```
select building
from section, takes
where (section.semester = takes.semester and section.year = takes.year 
       and section.grade = takes.grade) in 
            (select course_id, sec_id, semester, year
             from takes
             where takes.semester = 'Fall' 
               and takes.year = 2009 and takes.grade = 'A');
```

Comment: What databas do you use ? Samle data please, before and after the query.

Comment: it is from my university

Comment: This in clause does not make too much sense to me.  Usually you  are looking for a field  into a set of results for a particular field.  And you must specify and field in ( select field from.... ).

Comment: @anansi . . . You should describe the logic *in the question*.  A non-functioning query does not convey this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an AND condition in the tuple for an IN condition, and you are missing a JOIN condition for your main query. It is unclear to me, what exactly you are trying to achieve, but maybe something like this.

```
select building
from section
  JOIN takes 
    ON section.semester = takes.semester 
   and section.year = takes.year 
   and section.grade = takes.grade
WHERE (takes.course_id, takes.sec_id, takes.semester, takes.year) 
       IN (select t2.course_id, t2.sec_id, t2.semester, t2.year
           from takes t2
           where t2.semester = 'Fall' 
             and t2.year = 2009 
             and t2.grade = 'A');
```

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name I have removed the grade column join because there is no grade column in specifications of the table in the OP's question... maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @VBoka: there is a condition `and section.grade = takes.grade` in the original query

Comment: Yes, I know.... I am just adding an obeservation of mine that there is no grade column in the table specifications (table section ).